# Getting a "Variable Not Defined" error when attempting to open a table in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am having a very frustrating problem. I am trying to open a table in the currentDB that exists (I listed all the table names out using the following code:

```
Dim tbl As Object
For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    Debug.Print tbl.Name
Next tbl
```

The code opens two other tables without problem. (Although i did have the issue but when I coped my code to a new sub area it seemed to work ??)

I thought my issue was easy to solve by doing a Repair/Compact DB as that seemed to work on another table problem I had but this one doesn't yield to that solution.

Here is my code.....

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(“StkPrdSum”)

Do While Not rst.EOF
   debug.Print StkPrdSum![CurYear]
   rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

The error is generated when i try to compile. I get the "Variable not defined" error on the table name StkPrdSum in quotes.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to test this, but I think your reference to StkPrdSum in  "debug.Print StkPrdSum![CurYear]" is wrong.

As you declared rst as an openrecordset, your debug.print should be on it.

```
    Do While Not rst.EOF
       debug.Print rst![CurYear]
       rst.MoveNext
    Loop
```

I hope this had helped you, and sorry for my english.